# Find $ x_3 \ $ using iteration method

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

**Answer:**

We have to use Newton Raphson method.

$ x_1=0.75 \ \Rightarrow f(x_1) \approx 2.2 , \ \ f'(x_1)= ? $

I can not find out what is $ f'(x_1) \ $ ?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: $f'(x_1) \approx 0$... are u sure you have to use Newton's method?

Comment: any method can be used

Comment: remember that the above graph is the graph of difference equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your really need to know the function f(x) to find its derivative. The slope of the graph at x = .75 appears to be > 0.

Comment: help me doing this

Comment: The difference equation is a cubic with roots x = 0 and x = 2 and x = 3. x(x-2)(x-3) =?